# How do I specify the ordering of pages on readthedocs.org?

Tags: read-the-docs

I've got a bunch of md files in a folder, but I want to specify an order in which they show up in the index on the left. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this uses Mkdocs, and you can specify a yml file to specify the order

http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/

Comment: See also [related github issue](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2098)